# How to find a dynamically generated control using Javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript, tablesorter

I have Created a HTML table in code behind and added it to the panel controls in ASPX page.

Now i want to get the table using its id in the javascript to implement table sorter.

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
        $("myTable").tablesorter();
    });
```

it is not identifying mytable control that i created in Codebehind:

```
       HtmlTable Table= new HtmlTable();        
       Table.ID = "NavTable";
```

Please do help me with this tried many ways but nothing is working.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several choices. The basic idea is to output the ClientID of the control in interest somewhere you can find it.

For example:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#<%=this.TableControl.ClientID%>").tablesorter();
});
```

Or: if you're in ASP.NET 4.5 environment you can set the ClientIDMode="Static" and just hardcode it directly in the script. Beware, though, if you introduce an ID clash, ASP.NET will slap your wrist.

```
<asp:Grid ClientIDMode="Static" ID="my_static_table_id" />
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#my_static_table_id").tablesorter();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your example contains different ids `myTable` and `NavTable`. And you are using incorrect selector if you want select by id. Your selector have to looks like:

```
$("#NavTable").tablesorter();
```

So you forgot sharp in the selector value.

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues here.

1. You try to reference "myTable" from javascript, and you named it "NavTable".
2. Referencing a html element by id in jQuery needs a `#` at the beginning to tell jQuery that the selector is an ID and not a html tag name.
3. To be sure that ASP.NET doesn't use another id in the HTML output, you should get the `ClientID` value from the ASP.NET server-side object you created in C# (might happen if is declared within within an ASP.NET user control).

The code will then look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#<%=Table.ClientID%>").tablesorter();
});
```

For this you also need to declare the `Table` variable as a member in the class, so that the design code will see it in scope. Else this is only accessible within the method you created it.

If you know that this will always generate the actual ID you assign it, you can hard code it in the javascript like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#NavTable").tablesorter();
});
```